# How can I get 2 browsers to sync videos?

Tags: video, browser

I want to make some web based presentation software (similar to https://renewedvision.com/propresenter/) that will do video backgrounds etc, and I want it to support multi projector displays (for example 3 projecters side by side that overlap a little to make one wide screen). In order to do this, the video in each browser must be exactly in sync or you will see the lag where the overlap is etc.

Are there any suggestions how this is possible? I would like to do this natively in chrome/firefox (probably using something like javascript/jquery), but not sure this is possible, so if not, using a plugin or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any regularly used browser based solution to this - synching media across different platforms is quite a tricky issue without some sort of control signalling.

There is, however, at least one open source client based solution here which may be worth looking at:

- https://github.com/Syncplay/syncplay

For a browser based solution there are a number of examples that communicate  from each browser to a server to allow the server adjust the stream times or tell the browser to adjust the stream times to allow synchronisation. While it is possible to see issues with this in theory, for example changing delays in the connections for each browser, you may find if you experiment with it it actually will work for you in practice, although your case where the displays are side buy side will test them to the limits:

- https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c0bc/b42b63b6d88ebbb5fb4c6686662300d3611b.pdf
- https://github.com/povdocs/sync-player

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to work on chrome (in Ubuntu), but seems pretty good in Firefox. I might check out how it all works and use the concepts rather than the actual code.